# Libgdx - Adding button/image controls in game world?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, libgdx

I am still new in libgdx and confused, i want some button in my games(always in bottom left screen) for make some event (use item,  create soldier,etc). Where can i put this button in my games class? I have worldController class, worldRenderer class and GameScreen class (like in canyon bunny from libgdx ebook)
I have tried add stage and button in worldRenderer class then draw it in one of renderGui methods but nothing is shown. So, how to insert button to inside my game world?
Thanks...

```
public class WorldRenderer implements Disposable {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    public SpriteBatch batch;
    private Stage stage = new Stage();
    private Button btnItem;
    private Skin skinLibgdx = new Skin(
            Gdx.files.internal(Constants.SKIN_LIBGDX_UI),
            new TextureAtlas(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_LIBGDX_UI));
    private WorldController worldController;
    private OrthographicCamera cameraGUI;
    public float w = Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH/1366;
    public float h = Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT/768;
    public WorldRenderer (WorldController worldController) { 
        this.worldController = worldController;
        init();
    }



    private void init () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        camera.update();
        btnItem = new Button(skinLibgdx);
        btnItem.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("ABC");
            }
        });
        stage.addActor(btnItem);
        //background = new ParallaxBackground(layers,camera,batch);
        cameraGUI = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH,
        Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT);
        cameraGUI.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        cameraGUI.setToOrtho(true); // flip y-axis
        cameraGUI.update();
    }
    public void render () { 
        renderWorld(batch);
        renderGui(batch);
    }

    private void renderWorld (SpriteBatch batch) {
        //background.render();
        worldController.cameraHelper.applyTo(camera);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        worldController.level.render(batch);
        batch.end();

    }

    public void resize (int width, int height) { 
        //camera.viewportWidth = (Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT / height) *width;
        camera.update();

        cameraGUI = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH,
        Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT);
        cameraGUI.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        cameraGUI.setToOrtho(true); // flip y-axis
        cameraGUI.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        batch.dispose();
    }

    private void renderGuiScore (SpriteBatch batch) {
        float x = -15;
        float y = -15;
        batch.draw(Assets.instance.enemies.soldiers,x, y, 50, 50, 100, 100, 0.35f, -0.35f, 0);
        Assets.instance.fonts.defaultBig.draw(batch,
                "" + worldController.score,
                x + 75, y + 37);
        //stage.draw(); i have try draw in this line too but UI become dissapear
    }

    private void renderGuiExtraLive (SpriteBatch batch) {
        float x = cameraGUI.viewportWidth - 50 - Constants.LIVES_START*50;
        float y = -15*h;
        for (int i = 0; i < Constants.LIVES_START; i++) {
            if (worldController.lives <= i)
            batch.setColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
            batch.draw(Assets.instance.hero.hero1,
            x + i * 50, y, 50, 50, 120, 100, 0.35f, -0.35f, 0);
            batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }
    }

    private void renderGuiHealth (SpriteBatch batch) {
        float x = 50;
        float y = -15*h;
        for (int i = 0; i < Constants.LIVES_START; i++) {
            if (worldController.lives <= i)
            batch.setColor(Color.RED);
            float health = worldController.level.hero.getHealth();
            Assets.instance.fonts.defaultBig.draw(batch,
                    "" + Math.round(health),
                    x + 75, y + 37);
        }
    }

    private void renderGuiEnergy (SpriteBatch batch) {
        float x = 125;
        float y = -15*h;
        for (int i = 0; i < Constants.LIVES_START; i++) {
            if (worldController.lives <= i)
            batch.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            float energy = worldController.level.hero.getEnergy();
            Assets.instance.fonts.defaultBig.draw(batch,
                    "" + Math.round(energy),
                    x + 75, y + 37);
        }
    }

    private void renderGuiPlasma (SpriteBatch batch) {
        float x = 200;
        float y = -15*h;
        for (int i = 0; i < Constants.LIVES_START; i++) {
            if (worldController.lives <= i)
            batch.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            Assets.instance.fonts.defaultBig.draw(batch,
                    "" + worldController.level.hero.getUltimateEnergy() + "-" + worldController.level.hero.getPower() + "-" + worldController.plasma,
                    x + 75, y + 37);

        }
    }

    private void renderGui (SpriteBatch batch) {
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cameraGUI.combined);
        batch.begin();
        // draw collected gold coins icon + text
        // (anchored to top left edge)
        renderGuiScore(batch);
        // draw extra lives icon + text (anchored to top right edge)
        renderGuiExtraLive(batch);
        //draw Health
        renderGuiHealth(batch);
        //draw Energy
        renderGuiEnergy(batch);
        //draw Plasma
        renderGuiPlasma(batch);
        batch.end();
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten:

```
stage.act();
```

And set the input processor:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```